# How to run command for every line in visual linewise mode in vim

Tags: vim

I have the following CSS that I want to comment out with "//" at the beginning of each line (using Sass).

```
a:focus {                                                                                                                  
    outline: thin dotted;                                                                                           
}
```

With my cursor on the first line I enter visual linewise mode and select 3 lines <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>.   To comment I type <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>.  What I expect to happen is all lines have the text "//" prepended but instead only the first line has been modified.

Alternatively if I use visual blockwise mode to select (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>) the lines and press <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> I receive the expected result of all lines prepended with "//".

My assumption has been that linewise and blockwise modes were merely different ways to select text.  If I wanted to select all text of multiples lines the selection commands were interchangeable as long as I was able to select the text to modify.  But the behavior above leads me to believe there's a difference I don't yet understand.

Is it possible to use visual linewise mode to accomplish this task or is it just the wrong tool for the job?  Also documentation on the differences between the two modes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i'd like to think visual mode wraps like a span and visual block chunks like a div in block. There are differences and you will find uses for both. I don't see a problem in this question though...

Comment: Updated with more specific questions specifically if there's a way to do this with linewise mode and documentation on the differences in the modes.

Comment: The two references I use are the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki) and the [vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#blockwise-operators). I'm not sure why you would want to do a block event linewise but I hope someone sheds some light on your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character-wise, line-wise and block-wise visual modes all allow you to select text across multiple lines.

Character-wise visual mode is mainly useful when you don't care about or don't want to deal with "lines".

Line-wise visual mode is to be used when dealing with whole lines is important.

Block-wise visual mode is a convenient way to repeat a change across multiple similar lines. I like to see it like "a window inside the window" that allows me to act on a subset of my current buffer.

The one you choose is dictated by what you plan to do with that selection but their behavior differs *only* when doing visual mode commands: because Ex commands are always line-wise, they don't care about the specifics of your visual mode beyond the first line and the last line of the selection.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Marking as the answer as this was the most problematic part of it.

Answer (score 6):

If you are in linewise visual mode you can use `normal` to accomplish what you want.

```
:'<,'>norm I//
```

`normal` runs the command `I//` on every line in normal mode.

Comment: Wow, hadn't seen that before.  Slightly different result than running `:'<,'>s#^#//#` but it accomplishes the job all the same.

Comment: @Brad you might want `i0//` if you really want it at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @FDinoff you mean `0i//`

Comment: @DhruvaSagar oops yeah that one.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use visual mode and invoke `:'<,'>s#^#//#`

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, that works.  But I'm still confused as to the different behaviors between visual blockwise and linewise.  I thought they were means to the same end but they appear to have different behaviors when invoking commands on the selected text.

Comment: If you think about it, that's how it should be. Visual Block Mode is meant for operations on block rather than lines. If Visual Block Mode and Visual Line mode were the same then that would be redundancy.

However if you start a visual mode or a visual line mode, you can always switch to visual block mode by invoking `<C-V>`